# Changing the new item button based on view

Tags: content-type, list-view

So, I have a list with multiple content types. And I have all these views that filters by content type so people can simply look at one content type at a time and see all the columns corresponding to a particular content type. One issue though is I couldn't seem to make it so that people can easily use the "add new item" button to create a particular content type based on a view. Is there a good way to achieve this other than to change the default content type? Or would I be forced to essentially do some js magic with it?

[image: Add New Item Button Illustration]

Comment: You can't do it OOTB, but as you mentioned a little JS magic should get you where you want without too much hassle :)

Comment: It's actually a bigger hassle than it seems since I'll have to change every single view to include that JS file. I have about 100 views with this thing... :(

I also was wishing that I can use quick edit to copy and paste custom content types but looks like that doesn't work either...

Comment: Ah yeah - if only you havn't created the views before adding the JS then it would have carried over...